# Cannot Deploy the container image to Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

I am getting the following "permission denied" error when trying to deploy an image to Cloud Run:

> Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: 
>   Failed to load /usr/local/bin/dumb-init: permission denied

The Dockerfile contains these instructions:

```
....
....
ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
....
....
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
```

The image runs successfully locally but cannot be deployed to Cloud run due to the above error.

Comment: I don't have an answer. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish in Cloud Run with dumb-init. However, you need to be launching a process that responds to HTTP requests on $PORT otherwise Cloud Run will kill your container. You are not including enough of your project to reproduce anything.

Comment: As far as I can tell, @JohnHanley is right,  you should be starting a process listening on `PORT` env var. But this doesn't really explain the `permission denied` error. Also note that Cloud Run doesn't allow passing extra arguments to your process, so you're actually executing ["dumb-init", "--"]. I'm surprised it runs fine locally.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, you can apply [this change](https://github.com/browserless/chrome/pull/517/files) to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the binary directly
Since dumb-init is released as a statically-linked binary, you can usually just plop it into your images. Here's an example of doing that in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN wget -O /usr/local/bin/dumb-init https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.2/dumb-init_1.2.2_amd64

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
```

[More info on downloading the binary directly.](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init#option-4-downloading-the-binary-directly)